# A Set of Commuting Operators Has a Common Eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A_1, A_2,\ldots$ be a (possibly infinite) set of linear operators on a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$ such that $$A_iA_j=A_jA_i$$ for all $i$ and $j$. How to prove that all operators $A_1, A_2,\ldots$ have common eigenvector?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try to work by induction on the dimension of the vector space?

Comment: How do you get an infinite set with a finite vector space? Does your set contain linear combinations of a certain basis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commuting operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115793/commuting-operators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma:** let
$$V_{\lambda}^{m}(A) = \{v\in V|(A - \lambda E)^{m}v = 0\}$$
For any $A\in\{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$. Then for any $B\in\{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$
$$B(V_{\lambda}^{m}(A))\subset V_{\lambda}^{m}(A).$$

**Proof:** if $v\in V_{\lambda}^{m}(A)$ then $(A - \lambda E)^{m}Bv = B(A - \lambda E)^{m}v = 0.$ **QED**

**Induction on the dimension:**

Consider two special cases:

**First:** there is operator $A\in\{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ with tho different eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Then subspace
$$W = V_{\lambda_1}^{n}(A) \subsetneq V$$
is invariant under the action of any operator $A_i$ (by lemma) and
$$\dim W < \dim V.$$
So by induction $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ have common eigenvector in $W$.

**Second:** all eigenvalues of any operator $A\in\{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ are the same. This case splits into two:

**1.** There is operator $A\in\{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ such that
$$V_{\lambda}^{1}(A) \neq V.$$
Then $V_{\lambda}^{1}(A)$ is invariant under the action of any operator $A_i$ and
$$\dim V_{\lambda}^{1}(A) < \dim V.$$
So by induction $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ have common eigenvector in $V_{\lambda}^{1}(A)$.

**2.** For any $A\in\{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$
$$V_{\lambda}^{1}(A) = V.$$
Then any vector of $V$ is common eigenvector of operators $A_1, A_2, \ldots$. **QED**

Can you check my solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you only need the "second" case?  If some $A$ is not a multiple of the identity, then let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$.  Then $0 < V_{\lambda}^1 < V$. Hence $V_{\lambda}^1$ is a non-zero space invariant under all $A_i$'s, so by induction, it contains a common (non-zero) eigenvector of all the $A_i$'s.