# Two linear operators in a complex Euclidean space have a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

The question is the following:

**Let $E$ a complex Euclidean space. Let $S,T:E \rightarrow E$ linear operators with $ST=TS$. Show that $ST$ has a common eigenvector.**

My idea is to use that fact that:

$ST=TS \Longleftrightarrow S$ autospaces are invariant by $T$. I know that means it exists a orthonormal base of $E$ that is made by the eigenvectors  of $S$ and $T$. How can I guarantee there is a common one?

Comment: Do you mean : "show that $S$ , $T$ have a common eigenvector" above? Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131782/a-set-of-commuting-operators-has-a-common-eigenvector?rq=1) answer your question? Does [this also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115793/commuting-operators) answer your question?

Comment: In the textbook I took the question from it says "Show that $ST$ has a common eigenvector". I also thought it sounded weird. Is it unanswerable like this?

Comment: Definitely sounds weird, I mean, something can be common amongst two or more things, but there's only one thing i.e. $ST$ in there. I'm sure that $S,T$ is meant there. Typo!

Comment: @2BDrB Yes, the question is unanswerable unless you interpret the last $ST$ as $S,T$.